# Redefinindo como uma função opera? C

Tags: c, ponteiro

Olá, estou com uma dúvida em relação a uma linha do código abaixo, vejam:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef float (*TPonteiroFuncao)(float, float); // O QUE ESSA LINHA FAZ?

float soma(float a, float b){
    return a+b;
}

float produto(float a, float b){
    return a*b;
}

int main(){
    TPonteiroFuncao pfs,pfp;
    float r; 

    pfs = &soma;
    pfp = &produto;
    r = pfs(12,14);
    printf("Resultado: %.2f\n", r);
    r = pfp(12,14);
    printf("Resultado: %.2f\n", r);

    return 0;
}
```

A linha em questão está redefinindo como as funções criados com o tipo float vão operar? Ou seria apenas a criação de um nome, de modo que toda vez que eu precisar de um ponteiro `float` basta digitar `TPonteiroFuncao`?

Qual a necessidade de `(float, float);` e o que ele faz?

Obrigado!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TPonteiroFuncao` é um *typedef*, ou seja, define um nome/apelido para um tipo, no seu caso, um tipo função/ponteiro para função. Uma definição de tipo para *função* é marcado por sua assinatura, que é composta pelos parâmetros de entrada e retorno de uma função.

Então: `typedef float (*TPonteiroFuncao)(float, float);` define que para ser do tipo `TPonteiroFuncao`, a função deve ter retorno `float`, e dois parâmetros de entrada também do tipo `float`, o `(float, float)` que você perguntou.

Abaixo temos um exemplo mais claro:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef float (*TPonteiroFuncao)(float, float); // O QUE ESSA LINHA FAZ?

float soma(float a, float b){
    return a+b;
}

float produto(float a, float b){
    return a*b;
}

int main(){
    int entrada;
    TPonteiroFuncao acao;
    float resultado; 

    printf("0 - produto;1 - soma\n");
    scanf("%d", &entrada);

    if (entrada)
        acao = soma;
    else
        acao = produto;

    resultado = acao(12, 14);
    printf("Resultado: %.2f\n", resultado);
```

Até aqui, acho que você já deve ter entendido mais ou menos como funciona, então vamos à um caso negativo, uma função que não contém essa assinatura.

Então suponhamos que eu queira outra operação, o quadrado do número:

```
float quadrado(float x) {
    return x * x;
}
```

E defino na minha entrada:

```
if (entrada == 2)
    acao = quadrado;
else ...
```

Recebo uma mensagem do compilador: `warning: incompatible pointer types assigning to 'TPonteiroFuncao' (aka 'float (*)(float, float)') from 'float (float)'` porque a assinatura da função, difere da definida em `TPonteiroFuncao`.

Answer (score 1):

A palavra-chave `typedef` tem o propósito de associar um *nome* a um *tipo*.

Trata-se de uma construção de linguagem muito usada para simplificar a sintaxe de declaração de estruturas de dados complexas, fornecendo nomes mais descritivos (humanamente legíveis) para os tipos, veja só:

```
/* Inteiro */
typedef int INTEIRO;

/* Ponteiro para char */
typedef char* PSTRING;   

/* Array de chars */
typedef char CPF[11+1];  

/* Estrutura */
typedef struct carro_s { char * modelo; char * placa; } CARRO;

/* Ponteiro para função */
typedef void (*FuncXPTO)(int,int);
```

Possibilitando as seguintes declarações:

```
INTEIRO i;
PSTRING p;
CPF cpf;
CARRO c;
FuncXPTO f;
```

> **A linha em questão está redefinindo como as funções criados com o tipo
>   float vão operar? Ou seria apenas a criação de um nome, de modo que toda vez que eu precisar de um ponteiro float basta digitar TPonteiroFuncao?**
>
> **Qual a necessidade de (float, float); e o que ele faz?**

A Linha em questão é apenas um *nome mais legível* criado para simplificar a declaração de um *ponteiro para uma função* que por sua vez, recebe dois valores `floats` em sua lista de argumentos e retorna um valor `float`, por exemplo:

```
float foobar( float a, float b )
{
    return( a * b );
}
```

Veja só como seu programa poderia fazer mais proveito do `typedef` e dos ponteiros para função:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef float (FuncType)(float, float);

float soma(float a, float b){
    return a+b;
}

float produto(float a, float b){
    return a*b;
}

float operacao( float a, float b, FuncType * pfunc ) {
    return pfunc( a, b );
}

int main(){
    float res;

    res = operacao( 12, 14, soma );
    printf("Soma: %.2f\n", res );

    res = operacao( 12, 14, produto );
    printf("Multiplicacao: %.2f\n", res );

    return 0;
}
```

Saída:

```
Soma: 26.00
Multiplicacao: 168.00
```

Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/TintedGratefulProcedure).

> *"Qualquer tolo consegue escrever código que um computador entenda. Bons programadores escrevem código que humanos possam entender"*.
>
> *(Martin Fowler)*